# Any way to set the Google Voice 'ringtone' in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-voice

I'm not sure if this is specific to the Google Voice extension in chrome or to just Google Voice, but I cannot find a setting in either, and neither can I find any information about setting this online.

Earlier this year, I started getting audible notifications that my Google-voice activated phone (via Sprint) was receiving a call.  Most of the time I get the notification before the phone actually rings. The ringtone is a bit annoying.  Well, my wife has the same setup and somehow she has a different (less annoying) ringtone, so I'm wondering if Google just randomly picks something or what?  We both have Google Apps accounts, so there's no difference there.  Any ideas?

Comment: First what phone are you using.  The second have you asked your wife if she changed the ringtone?  She likely simply changed the default ringtone for her phone.

Comment: No, this isn't about the phone's ringtone, this is about what gets played in the PC when a call comes in.  I've actually changed my ringtone on my phone a couple of times and it hasn't done anything to the ringtone that gets played on my PC.  We both have similar phones as well, I believe both are running Android 4.1 - hers is a GSIII and mine a Note 2...

Comment: Downvoters: this question is on-topic as it deals with a desktop Chrome extension.

Comment: After doing a bunch more playing and searching, it looks like it is not just Google Voice or the Google Voice extension but rather something in how Hangouts is available as a widget within Gmail. It seems I can get this to happen not just in Chrome but in Firefox as well.  Here's a page that talks about it:  https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3144495?hl=en  However, I still can find nothing about how to customize the ringtone.  However, one can turn it off by choosing to 'revert to old chat' within the Hangouts widget in Gmail. Or you could do this by signing out of Hangouts as well.

Comment: Sounds are related to "Sound Scheme" that you have setup in Windows. [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-sounds#1TC=windows-7)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there is no way to change the ringing tone in the Chrome version.
The tone that plays does seem to depend on the version of Google Voice and Video Chat you have installed.
If you have the older version (installed in Gmail) you get one version, if you have the Hangouts app in Chrome (newer) you get the other.